# what is the use of "mux." in pipeline command

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

This pipeline encodes a test audio and video stream and muxes both into an FLV file.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v flvmux name=mux ! filesink location=test.flv  audiotestsrc samplesperbuffer=44100 num-buffers=10 ! faac ! mux.  videotestsrc num-buffers=250 ! video/x-raw,framerate=25/1 ! x264enc ! mux.
```

I am not able to figure out what `mux.` actually does and use of dot in pipeline command during muxing,Can someone please explain or any doc for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot `.` at the end of a string refers to named elements. In your case `mux.` means `The element with the name "mux"`. In your pipeline you have `flvmux name=mux` - here the `flvmux` element instance gets the name `mux` assigned to it (via `name=mux`. The `mux.` then latter refers to that specific instance of `flvmux` (and not a new muxer instance for example).

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tools/gst-launch.html?gi-language=c#pipeline-description